CosmosClient alternate to CreateDocumentAsync, CreateDocumentQuery, and UpsertDocumentAsync when migrating from DocuementDbClient
I am trying to upgrade my project from DocumentDbClient to CosmosClient. In the existing code I have client methods like: CreateDocumentAsync(), CreateDocumentQuery(), and UpsertDocumentAsync() available but when updating the client to CosmosClient, I don't have any of the methods available. What is the easiest way to do this migration and what alternative do I have for these method in the new CosmosClient. Here's an existing sample method using the DocumentDbClient that I want to migrate and use CosmosClient instead:
 private async Task<ResourceResponse<Document>> UpsertStoreItemToDocumentDb(
 Uri collectionUri,
 TSt storeType,
 RequestContext requestContext)
{
 var client = await GetClient(requestContext);
 return await client.UpsertDocumentAsync(collectionUri, storeType)
     .TrackDiagnosticData(
         sourceName: () => ApiProviderSettings.Name,
         actionName: () => $"Upsert-{SourceMapping.ResourceDescription.Name}");
}

I do see using client.GetContainer() and then doing createItemAsync and UpsertItemAsync but before going that route just want to know if anyone has done this before what is the easy way to do this. Thanks!

Have you taken a look at the Migration guide? https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/cosmos-db/nosql/migrate-dotnet-v3

As I have mentioned in the question itself that GetContainer() is available and then I am able to use CreateItemAsync(), UpsertItemAsync() etc. It turns out that's the correct route as per migration guide as well and that's the way to go. Thanks!
